# What is the name of this mosquito-like insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

While I was studying, this insect fell down from the ceiling. It was alone and not in a swarm. It looked much like a mosquito but is quite larger compared to a mosquito..
I live in the Indian subcontinent (India).

[image]

Can anyone identify it??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a Crane fly ([Tipulidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crane_fly)), which is a large, cosmopolitan family of flies in the order [Diptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly) (true flies). There are about 15,000 species according to Wikipedia and some 500-odd genera.

The crane flies are sometimes known as "daddy longlegs" though this name is more commonly associated with arachnids in the order [Opiliones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opiliones). Both the harvestmen and the crane flies have long, jointed legs. Crane fly legs fall off fairly easily, so if you brush one off a curtain or your clothes, you are often left with a loose leg.

They are harmless, despite appearing like a giant mosquito. They like damp environments, but can be found almost anywhere there is pasture or forest nearby. They typically need a fresh water source or moisture for the larvae to mature.